# retrivininbg single column from the Sqlite database to display it in listview

Tags: android, sqlite

This is my cursor in database handler class for displaying single coloumn in a list view

```
public String getAllStringValues() {
        ArrayList<String> yourStringValues = new ArrayList<String>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor result = db.query(true, TABLE_PATIENT_GENERAL,
                new String[] { KEY_PATIENT_NAME }, null, null, null, null,
                null, null);

        if (result.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                yourStringValues.add(result.getString(result
                        .getColumnIndex(KEY_PATIENT_NAME)));
            } while (result.moveToNext());
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        return KEY_PATIENT_NAME;
```

}

as I m fresher in android please tell me the exact flow and code thanks.

Comment: Please post the stacktrace, or tell a little more about the error

Comment: So is it not displaying????

Comment: Hint: you probably want to return the `yourStringValues` list you're collecting and not just throw it away.

Comment: @laalto you are right. But  function returns string.

Comment: I'm not sure, but i believe, that fourth argument shall not be null, but you should pass in an empty `String[]` instead.